# Database Version Control on Cloud

Tags: mysql, version-control, cloud

I am currently looking for a version control tool for MySQL DB which is cloud hosted. The new application/tools needs to be cloud hosted as well.

I am interested in something which is free or have nominal charges. I looked over the internet but could not find a satisfactory solution. My requirement is very simple with the tools i.e. it should just capture all the changes to the DB and if required I can switch over back to the previous state of the DB.

Can you please advise some options which i can explore.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of tasks/tools you need to implement to consider the minimal DB version control support.

1. Source Control Repository - tool to physically keep track of changes made to files (i.e. git, SVN, TFS, etc.). Git is free.
2. Extract a representation of the DB - the DB needs to be represented in some kind of file format in order to be version controlled. It is not recommended that the database files themselves be version controlled, nor is it recommended to take backups of the db and storing those. You'll want to store the DB in a semantic representation, such as .sql file(s). There are a couple free tools that can be used (i.e. mysqldump, HeidiSQL). I like using HeidiSQL as it has a feature that allows you to selectively create dump scripts. These script can be stored in the version control system.
3. If you are looking at automation, you'll want to consider implementing a build server tool like Jenkins. Jenkins can be configured to poll a git repository and then execute build scripts (created by you) if it notices a change.

Some of my answer is subjective and I have glossed-over several intricacies of DB Version Control. You can research more questions about DB Version Control that have some pretty good answers and direction to well-written blog posts. There are also a plethora of paid tools out there that give significant DB Version Control functionality. To name a few, there's Red Gate, DBMaestro, Liquibase, RoundhousE, MySQL Workbench, and others.

I hope this helps.